# css - vertical align and responsive SVG icon

Tags: css, svg, vertical-alignment

I would like to vertical align an SVG icon but I can't figure out how to do it.
And in the same time I don't knwo how to make this svg icon also responsive in a way that I can easily change its size.
Maybe the svg icon is not properly formated...

fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/jc68skkj/

Thank you

Comment: Try to use `vertiacal-align: middle;`? https://fiddle.jshell.net/jc68skkj/2/

Comment: Thank you for your anwser but the scg icon is still not vertically aligned...

Comment: replace that `vertical-align...` with `padding-top: 2px;`, the heart sits on the baseline of text, which is the (correct) default position. Either pad the heart or the text.

Answer (score -1):

In order to vertically align content through `vertical-align` you need to do some preparations.

The parent container, in which your child container (including `vertical-align: middle;`) is needs to be at `display: table;`. Also, the child one needs to have `display: table-cell;`.

Those preparations will finally allow you to use `vertical-align: middle;` in your child container.

So that simply means, `vertical-align` can only be assigned to a `table-cell` element. Also, do not forget to take a `height` for your parent container. Without a specific `height` your parent will adapt to your child which means vertically aligning content would not be possible.

**EDIT**

I've noticed that you do not need to declare a table-cell inside of a table. At least, that's not necessary in your situation. Simply change your `.post-like` to this:

```
.post-like {
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the main div must be inline with other element. And vertical aling property doesn't need a display to table in order to make it work.